# How to set up Node.js file system to ionic project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to delete Folder/File in client side (Using javascript/Jquery/AngularJS1). I was Searching, finally i got using Node.js it can be done in [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-the-file-system-in-node-js/) link. Now iam not getting how to set up Node.js fs(File System) with either of the language.(Prefered language is AngularJS1). Looking for solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't delete a folder/file on the client side, imagine what could happen if you could do that

Comment: Using Node.js fs we can do this. Please visit https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-the-file-system-in-node-js/ once

Comment: using node.js you can do it on the server side not client side

Comment: Ok, How to set up our project to run the code which is there in this link https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-the-file-system-in-node-js/

Comment: you go to google you search for node.js you read the documentation really really well  then you see in the documentation that you need to install node.js on your local machine/server, you install it and then run the code provided

Comment: Yeah, i am going though Node.js. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var fs   = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));









app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.path);
   var path = req.path;
   if(req.path == '/'){
     res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
   }else
   {
     res.sendFile( __dirname + req.path);
   }
});
app.post('/app',function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body)
   var action = req.body.action;
   var data   = req.body.data;
   var fname  = req.body.fileName;
switch(action) {
    
    case 'upLoad':
       function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
               var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
            response = {};

        if (matches.length !== 3) {
            return new Error('Invalid input string');
        }

        response.type = matches[1];
        response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

        return response;
        };
        var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(data);
        var newPath = __dirname + "/app/images/" + fname;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, imageBuffer.data, function(err) {
                res.send({confirm : "uploaded" , filename:fname });
             });
   
     default:
       
}
})



var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

[Hi this is Application Folder which i had used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ubK.png)

In this Server.js file where i included node.js modules and load the application.